# Which statistical test should I use to compare land use type and species abundance?

Tags: r, categorical-data, excel, ecology

I have abundance data for a species of bird and data on land use type in the areas where the bird data was collected. I want to test whether land use type affects bird abundance but I don't know what type of statistical analyses I should use for this. I know the question is very general, but any starting pointers would be great.

Comment: How is abundance measured?

Comment: Along the lines of @Stefan's question, can you provide some additional detail about your variables. For instance, land use is categorical, but how many categories does it contain? How many different data points do you have per land use type? A few clarifications will help ensure you get a good answer for your data and your specific research question.

Comment: @Stefan - Abundance was measured as frequency of individuals observed within a 1 km buffer of a given route. Frequencies for each route are given for many years, so I will average them across years for each route. have frequencies over many years, so I will average them.

Comment: @MattBarstead - I’m confused about whether land use type will be categorical or continuous. There are 17 possible land use types. For each route (same routes described in bird abundance data) I know the number of hectares of each land use type along that route. I’m considering almost 4000 routes.

Comment: By "frequency" do you mean the number of individuals observed in the 1k buffer? What are "routes"? Is it possible to provide a snippet of your data set? This can be done using the `dput()` function for example: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html

Comment: Yes, I may have worded that explanation poorly. Bird abundance is measured as number of individuals observed within 1 km of a given route (routes just being different “roads” across the U.S. and Canada). For those same routes, I have the number of hectares around each route that fall into a land use category (17 different possible land use categories).

Comment: I’m on my iPad right now, so can’t provide any output from R, but I will update this post later with samples of the data. I believe the test I should use is a multiple regression, which, if I understand, will tell me how each land use type (independent variable) affects bird abundance (dependent variable).